# struts 2 listbox multiple preselecting

Tags: listbox, struts2

I have a listbox in my input screen(Jsp in struts 2) and I want to display the selected items as a listbox in the output screen too. I tried using the preselect option but I am able to select only 1 value.

This is my input screen listbox code line:

```
<s:select multiple="true" name="color" label="Color"  size="4" list="#{'1':'blue','2':'pink','3':'green','4':'purple','5':'crimson','6':'indigo'}" />
```

This is my output screen listbox code line:

```
<s:select multiple="true" name="colorN" label="ColorN"  size="4" list="#{'1':'blue','2':'pink','3':'green','4':'purple','5':'crimson','6':'indigo'}" value="%{color}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Description of attribute **s:select multiple** :

> Creates a multiple select. The tag will pre-select multiple values if the values are passed as an **Array** or a **Collection**(of appropriate types) via the value attribute. If one of the keys equals one of the values in the Collection or Array it wil be selected

**Array : *{4, 6}***

```
<s:select 
   name="colorN"
   multiple="true"
   size="6" 
   list="#{1:'blue', 2:'pink', 3:'green', 4:'purple', 5:'crimson', 6:'indigo'}" 
   value="%{{4, 6}}"
/>
```

or

**Collection : *colors***

```
public List<Integer> getColors() {
    return Arrays.asList(4, 6);
}
```

_

```
<s:select 
   name="colorN"
   multiple="true"
   size="6" 
   list="#{1:'blue', 2:'pink', 3:'green', 4:'purple', 5:'crimson', 6:'indigo'}" 
   value="colors"
/>
```